# Delphi fillpath

Tags: delphi, path, polygon, intersect

So first some background. Im developing a really simple 2D game, in Delphi 10.3, FMX, which at the bottom of the screen draws a random terrain for each level of the game.
Anyway, the terrain is just some random numbers which are used in Tpathdata and then i use fillpath to draw this 2d "terrain".
I want to check when a "falling" object, a trect for example, intersects with this terrain.
My idea was to get all the points of the tpathdata, every Y position of every X position of the screen width. This way i could easily check when an object intersects with the terrain.
I just cannout figure the way how to do it, or if anyone has any other solution. Id really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a Delphi problem but a math problem.

You should have a math representation of your terrain. The polygon representing the boundary of the terrain. Then you need to use the math to know if a point is inside the polygon. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

You may also implement it purely graphically using a B/W bitmap of the same resolution of the screen. You set the entire bitmap as white and draw the terrain on the bottom in white. Then checking the color of a pixel in that bitmap you'll know if it is outside of the terrain (black) or inside the terrain (white).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even tho its not really what i expected. Was thinking if there was maybe any functions that would help me.
I already have a background bitmap where i draw the terrain.. but the moving object for now is just another simple timage, so as i know i cannot use the getpixel or anything like it, except if there is a way, for example, to get the color of the pixel in the background. if you understand what i mean.The falling object is a spacecraft, imagine a game something like Lunar lander, so this timage has a bitmap with an image of a spacecraft, the rest of it is transparent

Comment: What I suggested is to have an additional bitmap (B/W is enough but you can use colors if you like) that has everything drawn that you want to check for collision (Terrain at least). Of course not the background of the game. You can avoid this extra bitmap if you have something in the spacecraft colors that is never in the terrain. This would seriously limit the color possibilities. To speedup bitmap checking, you should probably not use GetPixel but directly access the bits and bytes in memory using TBitmap.ScanLine. Need more help? Open a new question because StackOverflow is not a chat.